# How does one create and use a pointer to an array of an unknown number of structures inside a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure

Sorry for the confusing title...

I've been playing around with C++, working on a project to parse a game's (Kerbal Space Program) save file so I can modify it and eventually send it over a network. I'm stuck with storing an unknown number of vessels and crew members, so I need to have an array of unknown size.

Is this possible? I figured having a pointer to an array would be the way to go.

I have:

```
class SaveFileSystem 
{
    string version;
    string UT;
    int activeVessel;
    int numCrew;
    ??? Crews; // !!
    int numVessels;
    ??? Vessels; // !!
}
```

Where Crews and Vessels should be arrays of structures:

```
struct Crew 
{
    string name;
    //Other stuff
};

struct Vessel
{

    string name;
    //Stuff
};
```

I'm guessing I should have something like:

```
    this->Crews = new ???;
    this->Vessels = new ???;
```

in my constructor to initialize the arrays, and attempt to access it with:

```
this->Crews[0].name = "Ship Number One";
```

Does this make any sense??? I'd expect the "???"'s to involve a mess of asterisk's, like "*struct (*)Crews" but I have no real idea. I've got normal pointers down and such, but this is a tad over my head...
I'd like to access the structures like in the last snippet, but if C++ doesn't like that I could do pointer arithmetic.

I've looked into vectors, but I have an unhealthy obsession with efficiency, and it really pains me how you don't know what's going on behind it.

Comment: c++ has list and vector as a variable-number element array

Comment: Your "unhealthy obsession" is more of an "unhealthy refusal" to understand what a vector *is*.

Comment: You "don't know what's going on behind it" because you are struggling with pointers, arrays and heap.  That's all vectors really do, and they do it cleverly.  When you use vectors correctly, they are very efficient.  Now, if you are always obsessed with efficiency, ask yourself how much it matters.  I suggest you code for the problem at hand and do not over-engineer your solutions at the expense of clarity.  When you actually NEED efficiency, you'll damn-well know it.

Comment: But, unhealthy it is. Definitely. (@paddy perhaps, sometimes, deques would be even more clever, but your point is correct as it stands)

Comment: I recently wrote a [blog entry](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html) about some of what's going on inside of `std::vector`, that (among other things) has a bit about why it's probably more efficient than what you're trying to do instead.

Comment: Jerry, y u post link to blog I no have permission to read?

Comment: @DeadMG: Because I screwed up. My apologies. With a bit of luck, I've fixed the link now.

Comment: It does (kinda, it's not in code tags so you can't see `<typename T>`, for example). By the way, if you want to know what's going on behind a vector then *read the header*. If you are obsessed with efficiency, then you should know that the efficient approach to performance is to build the simplest thing that could possibly work, then profile and find the slow parts and replace them. So unless you have hard evidence that `vector` can't work (and it most definitely is the simplest thing), using it is simply the efficient thing to do.

Comment: @sehe yeah deques are indeed clever and probably have a reasonable intersection with what you might implement yourself if you wanted to incrementally grow an array to contain ridiculous numbers of records...  Actually, the poster hasn't indicated what type of efficiency they require: speed or memory?  You can't really have both.

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't think reading the header is the best advice for most people most of the time. First, the code is usually written more for the benefit of the compiler than a human reader. Second, it normally won't contain any explanation about *why* it does what it does. Without that, real understanding is much harder to achieve.

Comment: @paddy Ehhh, my problem was that I didn't know the size of the array at compile time... I won't be adding any extra things after the array is created...

Edit: Also, using this pointer to new array thing, I get both types of "efficiency."

Comment: @user1658731 Right, so in that case you should still use vectors.  Either `vector<T>::reserve()` with `vector<T>::push_back()`, or `vector<T>::resize()` with `vector<T>::operator[]()`.  Like I said, if you use vectors correctly, you get efficiency.  This makes for tidier and safer code.  If you have efficiency problems with vectors in Visual Studio, compile in Release mode and/or turn off `_SECURE_SCL` and `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`.

Answer (score 8):

Use vectors. Vectors are a standard C++ class which are dynamically resizable and carry their size with them. Using vectors your class becomes this

```
class SaveFileSystem 
{
    string version;
    string UT;
    int activeVessel;
    vector<Crew> Crews;
    vector<Vessel> Vessels;
}
```

Your unhealthy obsession with vectors is misplaced. Seriously I doubt if they are any less efficient than anything you might code. Do you think the writers of vector for your compiler were incompetent?

I see you are happy to use string. Why does your argument about efficiency and not knowing what is going on behind the scenes not apply to string? It's *exactly* the same situation.

Comment: It's a bit different, though. String is easier to use than it's pure array counterpart. A vector is different, with its iterators and whatnots. You also don't know how much memory is being allocated, or a simple way to access its elements. I appreciate the effort, though.

Comment: @user1658731 So, you have an unhealthy obsession with not wanting to learn iterators "and whatnots"?

Comment: I don't like them. You have to push back and can't jump around from place to place.

Comment: @user1658731 That's not correct.  You can use indexing **or** iterators on arrays.  And you can use iterators **or** indexing on vectors.

Comment: @Martinho :( Really? I swear you had to use some command to fill however much space with duplicate data. I might be being silly and you might be right, but I don't need an unbounded array for this. I could spend time to learn how to use vectors, but the below answer works and is much simpler, in my opinion.

Comment: @user1658731 Don't swear. Just read a little more. Assumption is the mother of all f*ckups and certainly of a bad reputation on a QA site like this.

Comment: @user1658731: It's not simpler *and it doesn't work*. `delete[]`ing your own stuff is *hideously unsafe and unreliable*, and it's *much slower* than what `std::vector` can do.

Comment: @user1658731 You come here seeking expert advice, and then you criticize it on account of you knowing better.

Comment: o.0 Why is everyone yelling at me? Please explain how it doesn't work? I got it working. And how is it unreliable? (Aside from programmer error)? And how in the world is it slower when vector probably uses it itself...

Comment: @Geeny: No one is yelling at you. THIS WOULD BE YELLING AT YOU. What everyone has been trying to tell you is that memory management for arrays of items are nowhere near as trivial as people think it is. The writers of `std::vector` put in a lot of thought to make sure their `std::vector` class doesn't catastrophically die with the presence of exceptions, etc. The fact that you demonstrate that you don't understand how `std::vector` works means you will not be able to achieve the same attention to detail as the writers of `std::vector` have achieved.

Answer (score 3):

Using std::vector or std::list would probably be the better (and more efficient) way to go, but if you really want to use pointers and new and such, you can do it like this:

Declaring the variables:

```
Crew* Crews;
Vessel* Vessels;
```

In your constructor:

```
// initialize numCrew and numVessel before doing this:
this->Crews = new Crew[numCrew];
this->Vessels = new Vessel[numVessel];
```

You can then access the arrays as wanted.

After you have done want you want with the arrays, delete them with

```
delete[] this->Crews;
delete[] this->Vessels;
```

The [] are essential.

Also note, that using "this->" is not necessary in most cases.

Comment: I know that, read the first line of my answer. The question asks for these things.

Comment: Thank you! It compiles and runs without exploding, I probably just need to debug a little.

Comment: @user1658731 why do you need to debug it a little? Are you unsure of whether it works? Why?

Comment: It's crashing on the "Other Stuff" I'm reading. I'm trying to use fstream to input directly into a bool value, which I guess is bad. I also had a problem with names which had more than one word... It's cool, I just got the program to compile like an hour ago... Using Visual Studio's debugger, the data is being stored correctly.